# Is there an easy way to autocomplete block variables in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

Usually Xcode autocomplete works really well for me but when tabbing through method signatures with blocks and block variables I always have to retype the variable types and names. Here's an example:

[image: block variable without autocomplete]

The animation block is easy to complete since it has no block variables and thus I only have to type `^{}` before I can start writing code. With the second completion block I have to type out `^(BOOL fin){}` before I can start writing code. This example is somewhat simplistic but with multiple types where some of the names are longer (such as `AFHTTPRequestOperation`) it becomes a pain and it feels like a situation where Xcode would otherwise autocomplete.

Am I missing some trick for autocompleting these block variables or am I stuck retyping them every time?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Tab until the entire block section is highlighted. Rather than typing, just hit return and the example block will be expanded.

Comment: This is how regular autocomplete works, sure. As you can see the whole set of block variables are in a blue cell so tabbing selects the whole thing, not the individual variables within.

Comment: yes, and when you hit return, the entire string of text ^(BOOL finished) {} will be written into your code

Comment: Thanks! I clarified the answer a bit.